# AWS cognito returning - 'Invalid Login Token. Not a Cognito Token'

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am able to successfully retrieve an identity token for my Custom Authentication Provider (Developer Authentication).  This is implemented using the Cognito devauth demo servlet.

This token is returned to a browser running AWS JS SDK.  When I make a call to getCredentialsForIdentiy, I receive the 'Invalid Login Token' error.

```
POST https://cognito-identity.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
app.js:150 Error: Invalid login token. Not a Cognito token.
    at constructor.a (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41)
    at constructor.callListeners (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41)
    at constructor.emit (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41)
    at constructor.emitEvent (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41)
    at constructor.e (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41)
    at i.runTo (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:43)
    at aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:43
    at constructor.<anonymous> (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41)
    at constructor.callListeners (aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41) "NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Not a Cognito token.
    at constructor.a (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41:615)
    at constructor.callListeners (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41:30513)
    at constructor.emit (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41:30224)
    at constructor.emitEvent (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41:16590)
    at constructor.e (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41:12285)
    at i.runTo (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:43:7277)
    at https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:43:7482
    at constructor.<anonymous> (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41:12495)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41:16645)
    at constructor.callListeners (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.58.0.min.js:41:30619)"
```

I am passing to getCredentialsForIdentity the following params.

```
identityId: <returned from servlet in region:guid format>
customRoleArn: <that maps to authenticated role>
Logins: <cognito-identity.amazonaws.com = token returned by congito>
```

I notice that new congnito identity was created by using id browser.  So, the token interaction with the servlet seems correct.  But the token is being rejected.

What am I missing here? How can I troubleshoot it further?

Edit: 
Browser client: javascript sdk, version 2.58. 
Essentially writing a JS client to [this demo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample) .  The modifications is only to get token as part of login call itself.  The generated token corresponds to a role that only has IOT client access.  (I wonder if that policy needs to expand).  Eventually the users will be validated against an internal ID store instead of this demo.

Edit 2:
Instead of calling getCredentialsForIdentiy against Cognito Service, I invoked assumeRoleWithWebIdentity against STS and that worked. The use of Basic Flow instead of Enhanced flow [here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) .  Really not sure why enhanced flow did not work but will take the basic flow approach for now.

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Can you give a bit more detail on how you're managing this flow? What you described sounds right, so it should be some minor thing.

Comment: Thanks! Added additional details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the AWS documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) is either inaccurate or documents an inefficient scenario.

Using JavaScript Cognito API, my Developer Provider returned token could not be used with [GetCredentialsForIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html) against Cognito API. (this is what prompted me to ask this question).

However, I can use the same token against STS API and invoke [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) which essentially returns the same response parameters as GetCredentialsForIdentity above.  This is the approach I took.

Basic Auth Flow documentation in the first link seems inaccurate. Because it lists 'get credentials' and 'assume role' as required steps but only one is actually needed.  Also, from a browser, this is an API call out to an Amazon service.  So using Enhanced Flow instead of Basic does not seem like an advantage if it worked.

Comment: I agree the Aws docs on Cognito are appalling. Had to switch to this setup, thanks for the tip.

Comment: 2021 and the docs are still remains confusing... Good approach

Comment: For anyone running into this in a GovCloud environment, all references of
`cognito-identity.amazonaws.com`
need to be changed to:
`cognito-identity-us-gov.amazonaws.com`. I was able to get the Enhanced Flow working with this adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, using V3 of the Javascript SDK, and struggled for a very long time!  The currently accepted answer worked for me - using the basic authflow instead of enhanced.

I am hoping to supplement the above with some information that other present-day readers using V3 of the SDK may find useful:

**On the server**, use GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityCommand from @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity to generate the token and send it to the client.

**On the client**, I was unable to successfully generate credentials with any of the following:

- fromCognitoIdentity, from @aws-sdk/credential-providers
- GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand, from @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity
- GetCredentialsForIdentityPoolCommand, from @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity

The following *did* work, using @aws-sdk/client-sts:

```
    const { STSClient, AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sts")

    const client = new STSClient({region: cognitoRegion})
    const assumeRoleCommand = new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityCommand({
        WebIdentityToken: openIdToken,  // the token your server sends to the client
        RoleArn: authRoleARN,  // the ARN of the role you set up on AWS Cognito / IAM
        RoleSessionName: userId // See note below
    })
    const credentialsResponse = await client.send(assumeRoleCommand)

    // the client apparently expects slightly different property names than the received credentials object
    const credentials = {
        accessKeyId: credentialsResponse.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        expiration: credentialsResponse.Credentials.Expiration,
        secretAccessKey: credentialsResponse.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: credentialsResponse.Credentials.SessionToken
    }


    // Example using SES, you may be using different services
    const sesClient = new awsSes.SESClient({
        apiVersion: "2010-12-01", // yours may be different
        region: "us-east-1",      // yours may be different
        credentials: credentials
    })
```

Note: [The AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityCommand docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sts/interfaces/assumerolewithwebidentitycommandinput.html#RoleSessionName) discuss what you should use for the RoleSessionName.

Answer (score 0):

I could obtain temporary credentials with [Identity Pool APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-cognito-identity/) only (no STS). I assume you have the idToken from the Cognito User Pool:

```
import {
  CognitoIdentityClient,
  GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand,
  GetIdCommand,
  GetOpenIdTokenCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity';

async function getAwsCredentialsFromIdentityPool(cognitoUserPoolIdToken: string) {
  const identityClient = new CognitoIdentityClient({region: 'us-west-1'});
  const getIdCommand = new GetIdCommand({
    // TODO: Enter your own account and identity pool ids
    AccountId: '012345678901',
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-west-1:e201dc59-9193-4577-94ee-d1133fbe31fa',
    Logins: {
      // TODO: Enter your own user pool id
      'cognito-idp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/us-west-1_123456789': cognitoUserPoolIdToken,
    },
  });
  const getIdCommandOutput = await identityClient.send(getIdCommand);
  const getOpenIdTokenCommand = new GetOpenIdTokenCommand({
    IdentityId: getIdCommandOutput.IdentityId,
    Logins: {
      // TODO: Enter your own user pool id
      'cognito-idp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/us-west-1_123456789': cognitoUserPoolIdToken,
    },
  });
  const getOpenIdTokenCommandOutput = await identityClient.send(getOpenIdTokenCommand);

  if (getOpenIdTokenCommandOutput.Token) {
    const getCredentialsForIdentityCommand = new GetCredentialsForIdentityCommand({
      IdentityId: getOpenIdTokenCommandOutput.IdentityId,
      Logins: {
        'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': getOpenIdTokenCommandOutput.Token,
      },
    });
    const getCredentialsForIdentityCommandOutput = await identityClient.send(getCredentialsForIdentityCommand);
    return getCredentialsForIdentityCommandOutput.Credentials;
  }
}
```